# Run two versions of the same unmanaged dll (referenced by C#-app)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll

**Background**

I have two softwares, written in C#, using the same third-party dll to get telephony-capabilities.

**Problem**

When I deploy a new version of one of these softwares, I also deploy a new version of the dll. This one overwrites the references to the older dll, causing my other software to stop working, since the new dll isn't backwards compatible.

**Attempted solutions**

- Deploy the new software with a registration-free version of the dll.
  This doesn't work since the dll doesn't have a strong name. Result from sn:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>sn.exe -e "theDll.dll" key
>
> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility Version 4.0.30319.17929
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> theDll.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly

- Ask the vendor for a strongly named version

This resulted in a "huh?". The dll works well however, so I don't want to look for a new vendor if I dont *really* have to.

- Give the dll a strong name using ildasm:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>ildasm.exe "theDll.dll" /out=theDll.il
>
> error : 'theDll.dll' has no valid CLR header and cannot be disassembled

Which seems to imply that the dll is unmanaged, and thus not possible to strongly name (if I'm not mistaken).

- Use SetDllDirectory and LoadLibrary to load the correct version of the dll.
  This seems to kinda work, at least I can load the correct dll from a specified place without registering it. This seems like a rather involved way to do it though.

**Questions**

- Has anyone done this the "LoadLibrary"-way and can verify that it works well for a dll where you need to instantiate some classes?
- Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: How do you currently load and locate the dll? Using COM and the registry?

Comment: @PMF Currently I use Visual studios Add Reference->COM and register the dll using regsvr32 (manually) or use the setup project to "RegAsCom" (sorry, can't remember exact wording).  But that doesn't allow me to choose the version.

Comment: @Hans Passant Yes, it is a COM. Can you give me some details on your suggestion? If it that works it would seem like the easiest solution for my problems.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375142%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks for your answer btw, I read it, but it wasn't detailed enough for me to be able to utilize it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This instruction told me how to construct an appropriate manifest file for an unmanaged COM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

A few important points I don't feel they covered so that I easily understood:

- Oleview.exe is one way of getting the info you'll need for the manifest. It is possible to find your dll both by using *Object classes-> All objects* (provided it is registered with regsvr32) or by using *File-> View TypeLib*. I felt both these were needed before I had all information (they display different information).
- When you have your manifest file, it is sufficient to chose "Add reference" in Visual studio, selecting the "Browse"-tag and then the COM-manifest you created. After that, programming is exactly as if the COM had been registered. VS will create the manifest for your program.
- Of course you'll need to make sure your setup project deploys the .dll and its manifest to the same folder as your .exe.